# Ubnutu 64bit Grub does not works on Lenovo g50

Tags: boot, grub2, 64-bit

My laptop is Lenovo g50 with x64 processor. But I cannot install ubuntu 64bit(Tried 16.04, 18.04, 20.04) on this. Currently I Have ubuntu 18.04 32bit. But the 64bit iso installer gives error in grub installation step. What I have to do?

**EDIT:**
The Grub installation error is:

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

> Installer crashed

> We,re sorry the installer crashed. After you close this window, we'll allow you to file a bug report using the integrated bug reporting tool. This will gather information about your system and your installation process. The details will be sent to our bug tracker and a developer will attend to the problem as soon as possible.

Comment: What error on grub install? Are you installing in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive with an ESP - efi system partition. Grub errors if no ESP. Have you updated UEFI to latest available? UEFI update required for USB-C port issues 2017 thru 2019 models
ThinkPad models including the ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th Gen to 7th Gen), X1 Yoga (2nd Gen to 4th Gen), and P-series 
https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/ &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I was in UEFI mode. If I change mode to legacy mode, will be This solved?

Comment: What is specific error?  Best to install in UEFI boot mode if UEFI hardware. If dual booting with Windows you want to be in same boot mode as Windows. And Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI/gpt partitioned mode since 2012.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI